# Display images in FlowDocument

Tags: .net, wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I see these images in design but when I run the program no images
I even see the ????? when I run the program
How do I get these images to display when I run the program?

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument Style="{StaticResource Flow01}">
            <Table CellSpacing="2">
                <Table.Columns>
                    <TableColumn/>
                    <TableColumn/>
                    <TableColumn/>
                </Table.Columns>
                <TableRowGroup>
                    <TableRow >
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par0}">
                                ∩ Intersection
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par0}">
                                ∪ Union
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par0}">
                                - Minus
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow >
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph >?????</Paragraph>
                            <BlockUIContainer>
                                <Image Source="Images\VennIntersection.png" />
                            </BlockUIContainer>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <BlockUIContainer>
                                <Image Source="Images\VennUnion.png" />
                            </BlockUIContainer>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <BlockUIContainer>
                                <Image Source="Images\VennMinusM.png" />
                            </BlockUIContainer>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow >
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par0}">
                                ∩ Intersection
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par0}">
                                ∪ Union
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par0}">
                                - Minus
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                </TableRowGroup>
            </Table>
        </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with add existing item and take out the Images\
But I really hope there is a better answer